# Spring integration Javascript

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

On every page of my web application, I've a common header.

header.jsp :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/320x480/portrait/header.css" />
<div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
    <div class="ui-grid-b">
          <div class="ui-block-a">
              <a id="backButton" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-ajax="false"> 
                   <spring:message code="backButton"/>
              </a>
          </div>
          <div class="ui-block-b">
               <h3>GeoAccessibility</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="ui-block-c">
               <div data-role="navbar">
                   <ul>
                       <li id="french"> 
                            <a id="fr" href="?language=fr" data-role="button" data-transition="fade" class="ui-btn-active">fr</a>
                       </li>
                       <li id="english">
                            <a id="en" href="?language=en" data-role="button" data-transition="fade">eng</a>
                       </li>
                   </ul>
               </div>

          </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Address.jsp :

```
<script>
   $('#fr').click(function(){
      alert("hello");
      //treatment to follow
   });

   $(document).ready(function(){
       alert("here");
       $('#backButton').attr("href","/fdfds");
   });
</script>
<body>
<div data-role="page" data-ajax="false" id="page1">
    <jsp:include page="header.jsp"></jsp:include>
<div data-role="content">
    <forms:form method="post" modelAttribute="address" action="/address">
         <spring:message code="streetName" var="streetName" />
         <forms:input path="streetName" id="streetName" placeholder="${streetName}" />

         <spring:message code="streetNumber" var="streetNumber" />
         <forms:input path="streetNumber" id="streetNumber" placeholder="${streetNumber}" />
         <!-- Rest of the form -->

         <button id="submitButton" type="submit" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-ajax="false"><spring:message code="adressValidateBtn" /></button>

    </forms:form>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Address controller for getting of Address.jsp or post the form :

```
@Controller
public class AddressController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/address",method=RequestMethod.GET)

    public ModelAndView init(
        @RequestParam(value="language",required=false,defaultValue="fr") String language){
           Locale locale = new Locale(language);
           String[] isoCountries = locale.getISOCountries();

           Map<String,String> treeMap = new TreeMap<String,String>();
           for(String isoCountry : isoCountries){
                 Locale countryLoc = new Locale(language, isoCountry);
                 String name = countryLoc.getDisplayCountry(locale);

                 if(!"".equals(name)){
                     treeMap.put(name,name);
                 }
            }

            Map<String,String> tree = new TreeMap<String,String>(treeMap);

            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("address");
            modelAndView.addObject("address",new Address());
            modelAndView.addObject("countriesList", tree);
            modelAndView.addObject("previousPage","/index");

            return modelAndView;
      }

      @RequestMapping(value="/address",method=RequestMethod.POST)
      public ModelAndView validate( @RequestParam(value="language",required=false,defaultValue="fr") String language,@ModelAttribute("address") Address address, BindingResult result){
              boolean ok = true;

              //check-up data

              return new ModelAndView("address");
      }
```

}

As you see in the 'init' method of 'AddressController' class, I've added an object 'previousPage' having the 'url' value of the previous page. I would like to retrieve the 'previousPage' attribute in my address.jsp to change the 'href' attribute of my 'back' button(sitting in the header.jsp). How to do ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

like every other attribute:

```
${previousPage}
```

I don't see any reason to use JavaScript to initialize the href of your link. You can initialize it directly using

```
<a href="${previousPage}" ...>
```